# My PC Can Find School's Wi-Fi Network but Cannot Connect

Tags: 14.04, wireless

My Ubuntu 14.04 PC can find my university's Wi-Fi network but cannot connect. My PC can connect to my smartphone's hotspot but not the university's network.

When I enter my username and password, the PC prompts me to re-enter them.  This is a vicious circle.

Edit: I changed my wi-fi's Authentication method.When I selected PEAP,Connection Prompt was successful.

Comment: You could ask the technical people, at the university, who support the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

University networks often have additional requirements. My personal experience is that Windows automatically detects those and Ubuntu not. You can check on a connected PC what the connection requirements are and then use exactly the same on your Ubuntu PC.

As example my university uses the Eduroam network:

SSID: Eduroam
Security type: WPA2-Enterprise
Encryption type: AES
Authentication method: Protected EAP (PEAP)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the settings for the network. First install gksu by running 
"sudo apt-get install gksu". GKSU lets you run graphical applications like nautilus and gedit as sudo without damaging your system. Do "gksu gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SSID of Connection", replacing SSID of Connection with the SSID of the network. (the name of it) Then remove the line "system-ca-cert=true" and save the file. Restart and try to connect again.